# How to filter result only by month and year?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I use SQL SERVER 2012.

I have stored prcedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TEST_TLP]

    @DateFrom date,
    @DateTo date

AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select * 
    from Clients 
    WHERE DateReview between (@DateFrom) and (@DateTo)
END
```

As you can see I pass two parameters to stored procedure above and those parameters I use  to filter the result in where clause.

My problem is that I need to filter result only by month and year.

For example, if I have passed those parameters:

```
@DateFrom date = '2016-05-15' ,
@DateTo date = '2016-10-09'
```

According to stored procedure I will get result between dates above.But I need to get rows from start of the month `05` and end of the month 10 **i,e** the result should be equivalent to those params:

```
@DateFrom date = '2016-05-01'
@DateTo date = '2016-10-31'
```

How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `EOMONTH` function

```
 select * 
    from Clients 
    WHERE DateReview between DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@DateFrom,-1) ) and EOMONTH(@DateTO)
```

Comment: Why do I need -1?

Comment: -1 is  integer expression specifying the number of months to add or subtract to @DateFrom. For more visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh213020(v=sql.110).aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : 
Here

`DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@DateFrom)-1),@DateFrom)` this will give months start date i.e  `'2016-05-01'` 
And 
`DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@DateTo))),DATEADD(mm,1,@DateTo))` will give month end date i.e `'2016-10-31'`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TEST_TLP]

@DateFrom date,
@DateTo date

AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SET @DateFrom = DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@DateFrom)-1),@DateFrom)
   SET @DateTo = DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@DateTo))),DATEADD(mm,1,@DateTo))
   Updated ---^
select * 
from Clients 
WHERE DateReview between (@DateFrom) and (@DateTo)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
select * 
from Clients 
where DateReview >= dateadd(day, 1 - day(@DateFrom), @DateFrom) AND
      DateReview < dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(@DateTo), @DateTo))
```

This method allows the query to make use of an index on `DateReview`.  You could also do this as:

```
where year(DateReview) * 100 + month(DateReview)
           between year(@DateFrom) * 100 + month(@DateFrom) and
                   year(@DateTo) * 100 + month(@DateTo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EOMonth() function

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TEST_TLP]

    @DateFrom date,
    @DateTo date

AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select * 
    from Clients 
    WHERE DateReview between Dateadd(d,1,EOMonth(@DateFrom,-1)) and EOMonnth(@DateTo)
END
```